# Matrix and index on Python

Tags: python, function, matrix, indexing

I should write a function that receives a matrix of integers M of size N x N and two indices "ir" and "jc" and returns "True" if and only if, for each element x in the row "ir", M contains at least two elements equal to x outside both the "ir" line and the "jc" column. Why the list index is out of range?

```
def verifica(M, ir, jc):
    elementi_uguali = 0
    for n in M[ir]:
        contatore = 0
        for i in range(len(M)):
            for j in range(len(M[0])):
                if M[i][j] == n:
                    if i != ir:
                        if j != jc:
                            contatore += 1
                        if contatore == 2:
                            elementi_uguali += 1
                        break
        if elementi_uguali == len(M):
            return True

verifica([[8,0,3,-9,3],
          [2,3,6,3,-1],
          [1,2,5,7,-1],
          [6,9,2,5,3],
          [3,2,4,-16]], 1, 2)
```

Comment: you last row is missing one element

Comment: Yes, I find it later! Now works. Is the program written well or could I have reduced it?

Comment: @Vic questions about code refactoring / optimization / general improvement should be posted on our sister site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Indentation error on the break? It could be improved for large N, but that's more a code review.